# Stripslashes not working

Tags: php, stripslashes

I am using this code in one of my 2 step form, Here i am validating the form inputs at step 2.php and saving it in session, then in step 3.php page I am fetching the form inputs from the session. Also I am assing them to $formData array because I need to re-run the validation code again at last stage.

```
    $name = $formData["name"] = $string->formatInput($session->getSession("mechanic_buy_name"), 1);
    $garage_name = $formData["garage_name"] = $string->formatInput($session->getSession("mechanic_buy_garage_name"), 1, "None");
    $address = $formData["address"] = $string->formatInput($session->getSession("mechanic_buy_address"), 1);
```

Here $string->formatInput("STRING GOES HERE" , 1) is my wrapper function which adds the addslashes function.

Let us suppose I enter ASWT's' Tech into garage name

I use this sql query to save the records into database

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ". TABLE_MECHANICS ."";
    $sql .= "(name, garage_name, address, town, county, postcode, mobile, landline, fax, email, website, services_other, start_date, duration, expiry_date, datecreated, datemodified) VALUES";
    $sql .= "('$name', '$garage_name', '$address', '$town', '$county', '$postcode', '$mobile', '$landline', '$fax', '$email', '$website', '$services_other', '$start_date', '$duration', '$expiry_date', NOW(), NOW())";
    $query = $mysql->query($sql);
```

But when I see database via phpmyadmin I cant see any escape characters in front of the quotes

This is what, garage_name is showing in phpmyadmin
ASWT's'

whereas it should be something like ASWT\'s\' after addslashes ($string->formatInput(...)) is applied.

Please tell me where I am wrong and why addslashes function is not applying.

Is this syntax correct?

```
$name = $formData["name"] = $string->formatInput($session->getSession("mechanic_buy_name"), 1);
```

$name is not showing the escape characters when I echo it.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `stripslashes()` is the wrong answer to any PHP database-related question. It is **not** suitable for escaping data for mySQL. If you use it for that, you will have security holes in your system.

Comment: `addslashes` isn't meant for database string input. Read up on database escaping (or prepared statements if you're mildly ambitioned). In particular database escaping is just meant for SQL command context. The slashes aren't supposed to be retained in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the mysql extension (which you should not) I would use mysql_real_escape_string in stead of addslashes. Or mysqli_real_escape_string if you use the mysqli extension. Or use prepared statements.